# C# class definition from XML

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, class

In order to build flexibility into my program I would like to offer the user the option to customise the toolstrip buttons.

Behind each button there will be a class definition and all buttons will have the same structure; however, the structure will vary from user to user subject to how they will use the program. An example would be to have one button define a part-number and another to define the quantity or manufacturer etc.

My original thought was to put the definition into an XML file and then read the file as I draw the toolstrip to define sequence-position, colour and text displayed of each button and then to create the classes for each button from other fields in the XML.

I guess I could set a limit and hard-code the data-types for each but I wondered if this could be done dynamically somehow?

I have created an XSD from the VS2010 XML > Create Schema menu with my XML file open but it is specific to the XML type I have now, of course.

Comment: What is your real question because the answer for `I wondered if this could be done dynamically somehow?` is YES.

Comment: Try [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using `XML Serialization`.  But be aware that there are some limitations to this method because it will not pull all the graphs when serialized.  It will mainly take the public properties.  For more information see . . .

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

I hope thats what you mean by `dynamic`.

Here is a site that you might be interested in, but XAML gets much deeper than this

> A very simple UI Customization
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613545.aspx

Here are some more resources about XAML . . .

> I believe it was Chapter 18 or Part 4 where he briefly talked about
>   CIL code and XAML Code and how to dynamically load them . . .
>   [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-NET-Framework-Professional-Apress/dp/1430242337](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242337)
>
> This book is targeted specifically at WPF platform.
>   [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-4-5-Presentation-Professional/dp/1430243651/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1358010247&sr=1-1&keywords=C%23+wpf](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430243651)

Comment: Thanks, though I can't see how this would then allow me to build a bespoke class from the resulting XML.

Comment: XAML seems to do what I need for the UI, though I will have to move from a Forms Application to WPF. What I can't see is if the functional parameters that would be stored in the XML can be associated with the buttons configured by the XAML, thereby resulting in only one X[A]ML file?

So UI parameters (button colour, button size etc.) followed by elements for the field parameters (parsing rule-set: upper/lower case, numeric/text etc.) as it is these that would be used to define the class. The rule-set being defined by the user.

Comment: XAML is an all-purpose mark up language for UI (also known as a View) which can do anything from looks (colors, schemes, positioning) to dynamic animations.  It is even deeper than I can describe.  As for loading and saving process of XAML, you don't really have to mess with the file directly (everything is persisted including the culture, data, and more).  Once it's saved as a xaml file you can go in and extract the information with XML if you want.  But XAML is limited and you cannot declare a method as you can in C#.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this is the way to go for me. :)

Comment: You might be interested in this video also: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQW_z02rRA0 the speaker is anthony troelson (the author to one of the books).  he introduces wpf in a 6 part video.